# Spring bean initialisation failure on AMD 2nd Gen RYZEN Threadripper 2990WX 32-Core, 64-Thread

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, amd-processor

I have a Spring application that starts ok on an Intel 8 core processor, and on an Intel 16 core processor, AMD Threadripper 16 core, but not on an AMD 32 core processor, specifically an AMD 2nd Gen RYZEN Threadripper 2990WX 32-Core, 64-Thread.

It fails with this exception:

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-38] [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing global application context!
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'de.hybris.platform.jmx.mbeans.impl.RegionCacheMBeanImpl#0' defined in class path resource [psdtocache-spring-global.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
```

It is a Hybris application. But in the end of the day it is just a Spring application.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

By now I have tested it on two different machines with this processor. All other components are the same. JDK and all.

I did try run it from docker specifying 16 cores (lets say, it is too fast and there some issue with the app, so I set 16 cores, then 8 cores for the docker image), with the same result.

--

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace and try to create a [mcve]. Given the `NullPointerException`, this might point to a race condition, insufficient synchronization or locking, or another type of concurrency bug during initialization. It might just happen to work on Intel, and not on AMD, due to differences in their architecture, it could also be some kind of OS or processor bug, or maybe incorrect optimization in Java, but that is - I think - less likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, to "fix" this what I did is in BIOS, turn off the SMT 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading setting .

And actually it starts compile project faster and run the app way faster too.

5 minutes in intel i7 (8 cores) vs 1 minute.

So.. is this JDK probelem (I would say), Processor problem or App problem? (do not know yet). Just answering how to "fix" it to let the app start.